# Вывод данных из массива images

Tags: php

Вывожу данные:

```
 $imagsss = $child->params;
 echo $imagsss;
```

выдает — `{"category_layout":"","image":"images\/yootheme\/blog_icons.jpg"}`

как вывести чисто `image`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$imagsss = json_decode($child->params, TRUE);
echo $imagsss['image'];
```